# Laravel Homestead - where to run npm (virtual machine vs. Windows 10 host)

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, homestead

I am running a Laravel Homestead Vagrant box on Windows 10 host. Currently, I am compiling assets (running `npm run dev`) inside the vm. It's pretty slow at times, and I usually have problems with symlinks, running watchers etc. - in short, there is more configuration required that I *think* is necessary,

Would it be better to compile assets directly on the host (Windows) machine? Are there any 'gotchas' I should have in mind? Does it really matter on what machine JavaScript assets are compiled? That is, will the compiled version work 'in production' no matter where I compiled it?

Comment: `npm run x` will run scripts defined in your package.json, without seeing those hard to say what it's actually building.  In general you can get good performance in a VM if the disk size is fixed and you allocate enough resources to the VM

Comment: The scripts are just default scripts coming out of the box with Laravel 5.5. I only modify them a little, to make them work on Windows host. I always follow steps from there: https://github.com/laravel/docs/issues/3345

Comment: Not seeing the package.json in the homestead git repo can you post it here or a link to it? https://github.com/laravel/homestead  In general it can work to build things on one platform then deploy to another especially things which are interpreted on the fly like PHP but would be curious what exactly is happening in the "build" script in this case.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Yeah surely webpack builds will be fine across platforms, in general people use webpack for doing babel and maybe some other transformations but ultimately it's basically es6 in and es5 out, but all JS processing so no system specific libraries involved there really.  Thanks for linking too.

Comment: So you'd say there are no big 'traps' I may fall into?

Comment: Yeah shouldn't be any issue really https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env <-- is what it's using to get rid of issues with environment variables on windows or cross platforms so imagine since they are using that to run the builds it should be platform independent.  generally can run into problems when building things that bundle libraries or expect certain runtimes in a given system, JS just needs a browser to run doesn't expect any other OS specific stuff so shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES. It is all right. I just tested it with laravel 5.6.

Comment: True :) I've been running it on the host for the last 2 months since I posted this question, and had no issues with that. Works both on Windows and Ubuntu hosts alike.