# npm doesn't install packages that listed in package.json file with Laravel/Homestead

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, npm-install, homestead

I have an issue with "npm install" on my Laravel Homestead, and the problem is that npm doesn't install packages listed in package.json file like laravel-mix... etc.

I have installed last version of nodejs and npm on my homestead machine. This is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your package.json file? Are you getting some error on the output?

Comment: I have provided it. Thanks

Comment: Could you add what npm returns when you execute npm install on the folder containing the package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but I think you should be running `npm install` on your host machine, and not in the vagrant box.

The end result of running scripts defined in `package.json` is the compilation of js/css which will be consumed by the browser anyway - there should be no difference where you run them.

I was confused by this for a long time, and finally realized it makes no sense for Laravel projects to try and run npm scripts in Homestead. I posted a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516218/laravel-homestead-where-to-run-npm-virtual-machine-vs-windows-10-host) back in January, and started running npm scripts exclusively on host since then. And magically, almost all of my npm-related problems disappeared (this applies to both Windows 10, and Ubuntu 16.04 hosts).

As an added bonus, the scripts should execute faster from your host, since your skipping the unnecessary 'Vagrant layer'.